# Linear Algebra - Is $M$ a subspace of $M_22$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $M = \{\begin{bmatrix}a&-a\\1&b\end{bmatrix}\}$ such that $a, b$ is an element of $R$ a subspace of $M_{22}$?

I think not since $M$ does not contain a zero vector. In addition, $M$ is not closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

How do I use a mathematical proof to show that $M$ is not a subspace of $M_{22}$?

Answer (score 2):

It's enough to say that since it doesn't contain the zero vector, it can't be a subspace.